# Transform data in a weekly view calendar with sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access

I need to make a weekly view planning calendar.

With that query :

```
SELECT  
      Num
    , name
    , DATEPART(dw, [DateExpe]) AS DAYOFWEEK
    , DATEPART(WEEK, [DateExpe]) AS WeekNumber
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WeekNumber, DAYOFWEEK ORDER BY Num) AS WeekLineNumber 
FROM Expeditions
```

I have some values like :

```
Num  Name    DayOfWeek  WeekNumber WeekLineNumber 
1    Test1   1          1          1
2    Test2   1          1          2
3    Test3   2          1          1
4    Test4   3          2          1
```

**Edit** I add the WeekLineNumber which is generated by the ROW_NUMBER()

I'd like to put it in a calendar like form (in ms access) and **my goal is to have that result** :

```
WeekNumber Num1  Name1   Num2 Name2   Num3 Name3   Num4 Name4  (...)
1          1     Test1   3    Test3
1          2     Test2
2                                     4    Test4
```

Num1 and Name1 are for the first day of the week. Num2 and Name2 for the second. (..)

There are 2 difficults OMHO :

- There is no computed data on each line (we can have more than one line per week)
- I can't have one line per record (which would be easy). I don't want that result for example :

```
WeekNumber Num1  Name1   Num2 Name2   Num3 Name3   Num4 Name4  (...)
1          1     Test1
1          1             3    Test3
1          2     Test2
2                                     4    Test4
```

I need to have on the first line Test1 and Test3.

Comment: traditionally, one would write some TSQL....

Comment: I see you have an answer.  OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

**Schema -**

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
      Num INT
    , Name VARCHAR(10)
    , [DayOfWeek] INT
    , WeekNumber INT
    , WeekLineNumber INT
)

INSERT INTO #temp (Num, Name, [DayOfWeek], WeekNumber, WeekLineNumber)
VALUES 
    (1, 'Test1', 1, 1, 1),
    (2, 'Test2', 1, 1, 2),
    (3, 'Test3', 2, 1, 1),
    (4, 'Test4', 3, 2, 1)
```

**Query with PIVOT -**

```
DECLARE 
      @sel_cols VARCHAR(MAX)
    , @cols VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sel_cols = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT CHAR(13) + ', [Num' + CAST([DayOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(5)) + '] = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek] = ' + CAST([DayOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' THEN CAST([Num' + CAST([DayOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(5)) + '] AS CHAR(2)) END), '''')'
        + CHAR(13) + ', [Name' + CAST([DayOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(5)) + '] = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek] = ' + CAST([DayOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' THEN [Name' + CAST([DayOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(5)) + '] END), '''')'
    FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

PRINT @sel_cols

SELECT @cols = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ', [_' + CAST([DayOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ']'
    FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

SELECT @SQL = '
SELECT WeekNumber, ' + @sel_cols + '
FROM (
    SELECT 
          *
        , id = ''Name'' + CAST([DayOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(5))
        , id2 = ''Num'' + CAST([DayOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(5))
    FROM #temp t
) t3 
PIVOT (
    MAX(Name) 
    FOR id IN (' + REPLACE(@cols, '_', 'Name') + ')
) pivot1
PIVOT (
    MAX(Num) 
    FOR id2 IN (' + REPLACE(@cols, '_', 'Num') + ')
) pivot2 
GROUP BY WeekNumber, WeekLineNumber 
ORDER BY WeekNumber
'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Query with enum -**

```
DECLARE 
      @WeekStart INT
    , @WeekEnd INT

SELECT 
      @WeekStart = 1
    , @WeekEnd = 7

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + ', [Num' + num + '] = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek] = ' + num + ' THEN CAST([Num] AS CHAR(2)) END), '''')'
        + CHAR(13) + ', [Name' + num + '] = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek] = ' + num + ' THEN [Name] END), '''')'
    FROM (
        SELECT num = CAST(sv.number AS CHAR(1))
        FROM [master].dbo.spt_values sv
        WHERE sv.[type] = 'p'
            AND sv.number BETWEEN @WeekStart AND @WeekEnd
    ) sv
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, 'SELECT
  [WeekNumber] 
,') + ' FROM #temp 
GROUP BY WeekNumber, WeekLineNumber 
ORDER BY WeekNumber'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output -**

***1. PIVOT***

```
WeekNumber  Num1 Name1      Num2 Name2      Num3 Name3
----------- ---- ---------- ---- ---------- ---- ----------
1           1    Test1      3    Test3           
1           2    Test2                           
2                                           4    Test4
```

***2. Enum***

```
WeekNumber  Num1 Name1      Num2 Name2      Num3 Name3      Num4 Name4      Num5 Name5      Num6 Name6      Num7 Name7
----------- ---- ---------- ---- ---------- ---- ---------- ---- ---------- ---- ---------- ---- ---------- ---- ----------
1           1    Test1      3    Test3                                                                           
1           2    Test2                                                                                           
2                                           4    Test4
```

Comment: It isn't possible I fear. I'd like to have on the first row both Name1 and Name2 filled otherwise I can't show it in ms access. (there will be blank line) PS : I bought your schema compare devart ;)

Comment: For example, you can generate query for all days of week or on the part of week.

Answer (score 1):

Using the dataset you have provided and loading it into a temp table #Test, below is the query which gives the result in the desired format:

```
SELECT  [WeekNumber]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=1 THEN 1      ELSE NULL END AS [Num1]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=1 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END AS [Name1]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=2 THEN 2      ELSE NULL END AS [Num2]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=2 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END AS [Name2]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=3 THEN 3      ELSE NULL END AS [Num3]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=3 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END AS [Name3]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=4 THEN 4      ELSE NULL END AS [Num4]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=4 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END AS [Name4]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=5 THEN 5      ELSE NULL END AS [Num5]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=5 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END AS [Name5]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=6 THEN 6      ELSE NULL END AS [Num6]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=6 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END AS [Name6]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=7 THEN 7      ELSE NULL END AS [Num7]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=7 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END AS [Name7]
from #Test
```

If You do not want to see the NULLs then use the below code: Nulls repl;aced with BLANKS:

```
Select  [WeekNumber]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=1 THEN cast(1 as Char(2))     ELSE '' END AS [Num1]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=1 THEN [Name] ELSE '' END AS [Name1]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=2 THEN cast(2 as Char(2))         ELSE '' END AS [Num2]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=2 THEN [Name] ELSE '' END AS [Name2]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=3 THEN cast(3 as Char(2))         ELSE '' END AS [Num3]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=3 THEN [Name] ELSE '' END AS [Name3]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=4 THEN cast(4 as Char(2))         ELSE '' END AS [Num4]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=4 THEN [Name] ELSE '' END AS [Name4]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=5 THEN cast(5 as Char(2))         ELSE '' END AS [Num5]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=5 THEN [Name] ELSE '' END AS [Name5]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=6 THEN cast(6 as Char(2))         ELSE '' END AS [Num6]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=6 THEN [Name] ELSE '' END AS [Name6]
        ,CASE WHEN [DayOfWeek]=7 THEN cast(7 as Char(2))         ELSE '' END AS [Num7]
        ,Case WHEN [DayOfWeek]=7 THEN [Name] ELSE '' END AS [Name7]
from #Test
```

OUTPUT:

```
WeekNumber  Num1 Name1 Num2 Name2 Num3 Name3 Num4 Name4 Num5 Name5 Num6 Name6 Num7 Name7
----------- ---- ----- ---- ----- ---- ----- ---- ----- ---- ----- ---- ----- ---- -----
1           1    Test2                                                             
1                       2    Test3                                                  
2                                  3    Test4                                       
1           1    Test1                                                             

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: It is not a possible I fear. Please look on the last example I gave. On the first line of the first week, I would have NULL value on the first line in the Num2 and Name2 column which isn't the good behaviour.

Comment: I have added the code in my above answer where the NULLs are removed and you get the same result as specified in your question.

Comment: well I think there is a misunderstand, probably my fault, the last result in the question is the result I didn't want. I'd like to have on the first line both Test1 and Test3 (please see WeekLineNumber)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. First, create the table (thanks to devart)

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
      Num INT
    , Name VARCHAR(10)
    , [DayOfWeek] INT
    , WeekNumber INT
    , WeekLineNumber INT
)

INSERT INTO #temp (Num, Name, [DayOfWeek], WeekNumber, WeekLineNumber)
VALUES 
    (1, 'Test1', 1, 1, 1)

INSERT INTO #temp (Num, Name, [DayOfWeek], WeekNumber, WeekLineNumber)
VALUES 
    (2, 'Test2', 1, 1, 2)

INSERT INTO #temp (Num, Name, [DayOfWeek], WeekNumber, WeekLineNumber)
VALUES 
    (3, 'Test3', 2, 1, 1)

INSERT INTO #temp (Num, Name, [DayOfWeek], WeekNumber, WeekLineNumber)
VALUES 
    (4, 'Test4', 3, 2, 1)
```

and then query it :

```
SELECT
      WeekNumber
      ,WeekLineNumber 
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 1 THEN [Num] ELSE NULL END) AS Num1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 1 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END) AS Name1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 2 THEN [Num] ELSE NULL END) AS Num2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 2 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END) AS Name2
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 3 THEN [Num] ELSE NULL END) AS Num3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 3 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END) AS Name3
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 4 THEN [Num] ELSE NULL END) AS Num4
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 4 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END) AS Name4
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 5 THEN [Num] ELSE NULL END) AS Num5
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 5 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END) AS Name5
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 6 THEN [Num] ELSE NULL END) AS Num6
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 6 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END) AS Name6
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 7 THEN [Num] ELSE NULL END) AS Num7
    , MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 7 THEN [Name] ELSE NULL END) AS Name7
  FROM #temp
GROUP BY WeekNumber, WeekLineNumber
```

which results :

```
WeekNumber WeekLineNumber Num1  Name1   Num2 Name2   Num3 Name3   Num4 Name4 Num5 Name5 Num6 Name6 Num7 Name7
1          1              1     Test1   3    Test3
1          2              2     Test2
2          1                                         4    Test4
```

Comment: I have tried your example, but couldn't get the result what's you specified in `which results`. May the problem lie in the input data? Please review sample data.

Comment: you are totaly right. I made a mistake when I wrote back the code for stack overflow. I corrected it and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do amounts to a crosstabulation or a pivot.

If you can import or link to the data in its originally tabulated (not crosstabulated) form, you may be able to crosstabulate right in Access.  Look into the access crosstabulate query, and the corresponding query wizard.

Comment: I think I can use a crosstab but the result wouldn't be the one I needed. My final goal is to create a printable report and also a form which will support interactions like click to have some details.

Comment: You can put a report on top of a crosstabulated query.  I'm not sure about a form.